# Compiling android apps with delphi 7

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-7

i was just wondering if it's possible to compile android apps with borland delphi 7 IDE, i know it's possible to do this using lazarus but is there any other way to do this because i can't download lazarus right now..
please help

Comment: Android did not exist when Delphi 7 was created. Do you realise that Delphi 7 is over 10 years old? Even the most basic research on your part would have led to an answer. If you want an Android app that runs on a wide range of devices your best bet are native development tools. So not Delphi.

Comment: I don't understand why this question has been downvoted and mocked.  I routinely encounter confusion among non-Delphi experts about the capabilities of Delphi versions and particularly now about the distinction between Delphi **7** and Delphi **XE**7.  It would behoove some people to remember that not everyone is as familiar with Delphi and its history as they may be.  I find it depressing that for some reason Delphi questions in particular get attacked/mocked as much as they get helpful answers, to an extent that I do not see in any other developer community.

Comment: @Deltics While that is very true, this is also something that could have been found with a very simple Google search. If you hover your mouse pointer over the downvote link, part of it says "does not show any research effort"

Comment: @Deltics Almost any websearch would have yielded the information. Some people don't make the effort.

Comment: That may be, but I fail to see the logic that leads to taking *more time* to make a mocking and/or condescending comment than would be required to simply answer the question without making *assumptions* about the OP's level of (or ability to) research.  As for not demonstrating research, they clearly had at least determined that FPC supported Android and were aware of some equivalence between Delphi and FPC.  It's not helpful to tell someone "you should know this" when they clearly don't.  Incidentally, your "duplicate" question is **not** a duplicate.

Comment: @Deltics Sure it's a dupe. And if you read the timestamps, the question was answered when I commented. My comment imparts advice. Specifically that the asker is clearly capable of doing the research themselves.

Answer (score 5):

No, you can't produce android applications using Delphi 7, The android support was introduced in [`Delphi XE5`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/What%27s_New_in_Delphi_and_C%2B%2BBuilder_XE5#Android_Mobile_Application_Development).